# Width: 100% is not quite 100%

Tags: html, css

I have set an element's width to 100%, but the border is not going all the way to the edge of the page, It leaves maybe a two-pixel gap each side of the line.

Here is my `HTML`:

```
<body>
    <div class="headerContainer">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my `CSS`:

```
.headerContainer{
    border-bottom:black 2px solid;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    color:blue;
}
```

Also, another question. I came across this code while looking through a website:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a>
        <h1 class="brand"><a href="#top">Legend!</a></h1>
        <nav class="pull-right nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul id="menu-main" class="nav">
            <li><a title="portfolio" href="#products">Out Products</a></li>
            <li><a title="services" href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a title="news" href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a title="team" href="#team">Team</a></li>
            <li><a title="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-inner -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
    </div>
```

And I cannot think of any reason to have that many div tags, Wouldn't one--or possibly two--do fine?

And a third question: if I have a `div` tag within a `div` tag, How will I reference it in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Include a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).  The few pixels of space on the edges are most likely due to some kind of padding or margin on the `html`, `body` or wrapper element(s).  `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` would also probably fix it.

2) There is probably not a need for that many nested `div` tags in the code you pasted, but it's hard to say without knowing the functionality (there is probably a lot of javascript involved in how that navigation works).  Even so, that code can probably be significantly improved / simplified.

3) You can reference a `div` tag inside of a `div` with the CSS selector `div div { }` which selects all `div` tags that live inside at least one other `div` tag.  `div > div { }` by contrast would only select `div` tags that are nested immediately inside another `div` as a direct child.

Comment: Perfect! Ill tick this when the timer goes away!

Comment: Good answer (I think you beat me by 30 seconds or so); just an FYI--`padding: 0` is not required here, only `margin: 0;`. :-)

Comment: Also, I need to stop the line break that <p> tags create, Is this possible?

Comment: @user3361034 The `<p>` tag by definition means semantically new content, which includes a line break. You can try `<br>` instead of `<p>`. Or apply a specific line height.

Answer (score 2):

The body element has a default margin. Add this:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

and your space goes away.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HcqY8/)**

And there's no real answer to your second question. The structure can depend on numerous things.

Finally, to refer to a div in a div with CSS use `div div {...}` to target any descendant divs of a parent div, or `div > div {...}` to specifically target the child div of another div.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line at the top of the css:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI `padding` and `outline` properties are not necessary here @user3361034

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `body {margin: 0;}` to your CSS. `Body` has a margin by default, and you need to remove it. Adding `padding: 0;` or `outline: 0;` (as suggested in another answer) is **not** necessary.
2. Sometimes you will need extra containers in your HTML code to apply CSS to separate parts of your content. One example is when you want to have a sticky footer at the bottom of your page be separate from the rest of your page's CSS rules.
3. Not exactly sure what you mean by your question, but you can select children of elements a number of ways. Without giving an example, you can try `parentelement > childelement` for immediate children.

Answer (score 0):

2) The large amounts of DIV's in your example probably comes from Twitter Bootstrap. I would claim that by the use of many divs and lots of separated CSS classes Bootstrap becomes a **flexible** CSS framework. Useful in different layouts and good for quick mockups.

You can definitely remove alot of of the divs and combine many of the css classes, and then you have made a **custom-made** html/css solution that suits **your** meny... and menues very similiar to yours.